# msvcrt-ruby18.dll not found when trying to use Heroku for Windows XP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dll, windows-xp, heroku

I have a student developing on Windows XP, and he's getting a strange error when trying to run `heroku keys:add`.  The error is:

`This application has failed to start because msvcrt-ruby18.dll was not found.  Re-installing the application may fix this problem.`

After about half an hour of trying, my google-fu has failed me on this one.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Tried reinstalling Ruby?  What version and patch level of Ruby?  Did you use the package from http://rubyinstaller.org?

Comment: It's Ruby 1.9.2 and he used the RubyInstaller from http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/

Comment: Try `gem update --system` and see, that such dll missing [are usual](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=msvcrt-ruby18.dll+heroku). In these cases I just copy it to `ruby/bin` from some another ruby installs I have on hard drive. Seems Ruby installers just sometimes don't include important dlls, and the universal answers on this question I still haven't seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI our solution was to [install Ruby 1.8.7](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/).  Since Ruby has added significant performance benefits in 1.9.2, it's not a great solution, but then again, neither is developing web apps locally on Windows XP ;)