# Install two versions of Ruby on XP (kinda safely)?

Tags: ruby, windows-xp, heroku

getting started with Ruby:
- Windows XP 
- installed ruby 1.9.2p0 a
-  rails 3.0.3.

Also working on sproutsource and have enough working right now that I don't want to mess things up.  However, Heroku is one thing that does not work, I get a msvcrt-ruby18.dll error and it seems that Heroku does not work well with Ruby 1.9.2 on Windows well, but does work with Ruby [1.8.7.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695373/msvcrt-ruby18-dll-not-found-when-trying-to-use-heroku-for-windows-xp)

So... will I screw everything up if I just install Ruby 1.8.7 (all those million slow gems I installed, that work great now).

I saw [Pik](http://blog.benhall.me.uk/2010/08/installing-rails-30-ruby-192-and-pik-on.html) which looks promising.  Any advice?

Comment: Pik is the main windows rvm alternative reported on the official faq page, I think there're no better options ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use pik and it works. You could also set up a Linux virtual box ([EngineYard has built an InstantRails VM using Vagrant](http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/virtualize-this-instant-rails-in-a-virtual-box/)).

Your msvcrt-ruby18.dll error might be due to the mongrel gem or the json gem-- [check out this question for how to fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3250406/msvcrt-ruby18-dll-was-not-found-with-ruby).

Comment: Yes, got Pik working with Ruby.  I use ruby 192 for everything except Heroku. For that I do >Pik 187.

Comment: The link above looks like it would work... but gem update  --system doesn't work with my 192 install, dies with a "`installed_spec_directories': undefined method `path' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)" , which looks like some, even non windows users get.  But, anyrate I have two installs of Ruby, got things basically working, and do recommend Pik for those with these errors.